# Android - ListView with Images

Tags: android, android-layout

I saw an app that had a nice menu structure which I want to replicate in my own app and wanted to know how you think it's done and how I should approach it.  Here's a screenshot:

[image: MECRM Image]

It's from the CRM mobile app (MECRM) and to me, it appears to be a ListView with headers and images.  But I'm wondering are they images or buttons with images as a background because of 2 things;

1.) the first image "Announcements" is cut off so if that was an ImageView, I'm not too sure if it would do the same.
2.) The Opportunity image has a different image when pressed (as do all the other images).

I guess my question is what controls would I need use to replicate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of view is absolutely possible using ListView

You're going to need to implement your own ListAdapter with custom getView behavior.
Based on the position of the view, you can either render an inactive divider view (that won't be clickable), or you can then render a gridview for the appropriate category. [This tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-add-divider-items-listview) can get you started on implementing custom adapters with getView.

Here's some sample code on what getView might look like

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    boolean isDivider = false //TODO logic here
    if (isDivider){
        if (v == null) {
         LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.custom_adapter_item, null);
        }
        Map<String, String> item = items.get(position);
        initView(v, item);
        return v;
    } else{
        View v = null //TODO init divider view here
        return v;
    }
}

private void initView(View v, Map<String, String> item) {
    String[] keys = DummyData.columns;
    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.value_left)).setText(item.get(keys[0]));
    ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.value_right)).setText(item.get(keys[1]));
}
```

You're going to have to inflate your gridview layout where I inflate my custom_adapter_item, but this is the framework for a custom listview with complex list items

Your view hierarchy will end up looking something like this

- ListView

  - Category1Header (LinearLayout))

    - Title (textbox)
  - Category1Contents (Gridview)

    - Cat1Cont1 (LinearLayout)

      - icon (image)
      - description (textbox)
  - Category2Header

You get the idea

Comment: It took a while to wrap my head around what you were explaining here but now I see it.  Thanks!

Comment: @Robert I sometimes jump steps in my head, or skimp on explanations when i get ahead of myself. If you want some clarifications, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a Collection of GridViews with 5 columns. ELement of columns are TextView, and ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

I think to get this type of layout list view is not sufficient.

You have to use ScrollView as parent, TextView and GridView as one layout and each this type of layout as children in ScrollView as below.

**child_view**

```
<LinearLayout vertical >
<TextView />
<GridView />
</LinearLayout>
```

**main_view**

```
<ScrollView>
<child_view />
<child_view />
<child_view />
.......
</ScrollView>
```

I hope it may help you.

Answer (score -1):

For something like this I wouldn't recommend Listview as a base. Listview is usefull if you have a lot of similar items that should react in a similar way. For small qty. Of items with a lot of variation it is not your best choice.

As basis I would use linearlayout or relative layout (depending on how you want to react on different screen sizes).

I would style TextViews with an according 9-patch background to look like the headers.

For the buttons I would use the Button widget with a selector as android:background.

Therefore create a XML file with below code in your drawable folder and exchange the drawable with the names of your drawables.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_add_sel0" /> 
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_add_presssel0" /> 
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_add_press0" /> 
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_add_norm0" /> 
</selector>
```

Comment: Argh could please somebody add the right ' to show the XML. I'm using my mobile and can't find the right char.

Comment: I made the changes for you, hopfully they will show up for everyone...but I see what you are talking about.  I will have to try this and let you know.